# Reusing existing application token of previous WSO2AM version

Tags: wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager

I am currently setting up a fresh instance of WSO2 AM 3.2.0 from scratch because upgrading and migrating from version 2.1 did not work as expected. To avoid any inconvenience for current users I would like to keep using the already existing `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` for each application so the `access_token` doesn't change when transitioning from 2.1 to 3.2.

Assume the `consumer_key:consumer_secret` being in use in version 2.1 is: `original_key:original_secret`.

When creating a new application in the AM 3.2 instance I, of course, get a new secret - say `new_key:new_secret`. To keep using the original combination I created a dump of the AM 3.2 database and in this dump I just replaced the new `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` with the original ones like this:

`sed -i 's/new_key/original_key/g' dump.sql` and `sed -i 's/new_secret/original_secret/g' dump.sql`

and then I replaced the existing 3.2 database with this modified dump. After restarting the AM 3.2 I can see that the application is in fact using the original `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` but when I generate an `access_token` it differs from the original `access_token` which I actually wanted to replicate.

I know that my approach is rather dirty but I'm wondering why it didn't work, though. Is there anything I missed -- or even better -- a clean solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for getting the different access token is that apim 3.2.0 only supports JWT tokens by default, in 2.1.0 it only supports opaque tokens. I believe that you are getting JWT tokens with the above token calls which are different from opaque tokens.

In the above approach, you will lose the following data from the previous 2.1.0 setup.

APIs and artifact related information.
Application attributes + existing active tokens + scopes
Users that persisted in the existing platform.

However, if you just want to replicate the applications with client id and secret, the better approach would be as follows.

**Using Devportal REST API**

1. Use the dev portal rest APIs to create the application[1]. When providing the parameters specify the token type as OAUTH if you want to obtain an opaque token.
2. Map the client-id secret pair using map-keys resource[2]

I hope the above will be helpful to you.

[1][https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#tag/Applications/paths/~1applications/post](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#tag/Applications/paths/%7E1applications/post)
[2][https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#tag/Application-Keys/paths/~1applications~1{applicationId}~1map-keys/post](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#tag/Application-Keys/paths/%7E1applications%7E1%7BapplicationId%7D%7E1map-keys/post)

Comment: I followed step [1] and successfully created a new application with token type `OAUTH` by using the API. But the devportal still tells me the token type of the application is `Self-contained (JWT)`. Also the API response contained `"tokenType": "JWT",`. Is this an error and the type actually is `OAUTH` or did it not work?

Comment: The case is that opaque tokens are supported but disabled by default in the 3.2.0 version. it's only supported for the migrated applications. You can do the following. navigate to the carbon console. and open the application through service provider configurations. please refer to the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/sSbAqlx . Then select the token type as default, it should change the JWT type to opaque.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but what exactly is the path you navigated to in the first screenshot? The breadcrumbs are not visible. Is it `Home > Identity > Service Providers > List - and then rest_api_devportal` ?

Comment: Oh now I see. I forgot to create the keys for my application, now I see the entry for the application under `Home > Identity > Service Providers > List`.

Comment: I followed the screenshots and changed the type to `OAUTH` in carbon. The entry in devportal is still telling me that the applications token type is `JWT`, though. Executing the API call for mapping the existing keys gives me an unhelpful error message `{"code": 900967, "message": "General Error", "description": "Server Error Occurred"}`.

Comment: 1. Please try to generate keys before mapping. there should be a service provider entry created for mapping the keys with existing ones. 2 .make sure that you have changed the token issuer as default in the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/iqXX5CY then only you will be able to generate opaque tokens. 3. even if we change the token issuer dev portal will not show token type as Oauth since opaque tokens are not supported by default. these tweaks to enable opaque token is still there since there could be platforms migrating to the 3.2.0 versions.

Comment: I can follow these steps until the last step when I try to map the keys. Executing the map-keys api call again gives me the previous server error. In the server log I can see `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Some thing went wrong while getting OAuth application for given consumer key orignal_key_i_wanted_to_restore`